# SQL LIKE search error only on one row of table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

This is weird, it never happens to me before

Im on the rails console, because my search form is not working, for some reason when i do a search using the row called 'nombre', the search doesnt work, this is the output data:

First, I will show you my table data:

```
  2.3.0 :035 > Item.all
 Item Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 1, nombre: "Melamina Blanca",          espesor: 18, material: "MDF", quantity: 14, created_at: "2016-08-04 00:56:13", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:05:01">, #<Item id: 2, nombre: "Melamina Gris Grafito", espesor: 15, material: "Aglo", quantity: 9, created_at: "2016-08-04 00:56:13", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:05:01">, #<Item id: 3, nombre: "Melamina Azul", espesor: 18, material: "MDF", quantity: 26, created_at: "2016-08-04 00:56:13", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:05:01">, #<Item id: 4, nombre: "Melamina Rojs", espesor: 18, material: "MDF", quantity: 5, created_at: "2016-08-04 00:56:13", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:05:01">]> 
2.3.0 :036 >
```

So as you can see, the first item, the name (nombre) is 'Melamina Blanca'

If I do the search, I get the following:

```
  item = Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "Blanca")
  Item Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (nombre LIKE 'Blanca')
  => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

So I tried to search by another row, on this case called 'Material'

```
  item = Item.where("material LIKE ?", "Aglo")
   Item Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE (material LIKE 'Aglo')
    => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 2, nombre: "Melamina Gris Grafito", espesor: 15, material: "Aglo", quantity: 9, created_at: "2016-08-04 00:56:13", updated_at: "2016-08-30 00:05:01">]>
```

I get a correct search, I tried with the other rows and all of them work, except the one I need, which is 'nombre'

Any ideas why?

Comment: @freciaj, Did you try `Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "%Blanca%")`?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @DennySutedja I think they mean that they're receiving a `logic error` rather than a `syntax error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are searching for an exact match. To search for a pattern string, you have to use `%` which defines wildcards.

Try

```
Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "%Blanca%")
```

This will look for records with names that contain "Blanca" in it.

If you want to search for names that start with "Blanca", use

```
Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "Blanca%")
```

Or for names ending with "Blanca", use

```
Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "%Blanca")
```

**Note**: Your search across `material` "Aglo" was successful because the `material` field in the record contained the exact string "Aglo".

Hope this helps!

Comment: you nailed it! i still need to figure out why on rails its not passing the search to the DB, its showing me the params with the data but then its not making the DB search

Comment: @frenciaj, its not making the db search? Look at the server logs to see if the query was actually sent to the database.

Comment: No, its not passing the query, its showing me the params but then there is no query with that search, i copied exactly the railcasts for the simple form, i dont understand whats wrong...

Comment: Started GET "/items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blanca" for 65.34.251.106 at 2016-08-30 03:55:51 +0000
Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blanca"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
  Rendered items/_items.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)

Comment: @frenciaj, can you post your code in `index` action of `ItemsController`?

Comment: Thank you Aron, i posted the controller, model and view, its on the answer below

Comment: i moved it to a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230097/rails-not-passing-the-db-query-on-search-form