# Rails not passing the DB Query on search form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search

Here what looks better, this is the log, its passing the param, but its not passing a query with that param

```
Started GET "/items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=blanca" for 65.34.251.106 at 2016-08-30 03:55:51 +0000
Processing by ItemsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"blanca"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
Item Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
Rendered items/_items.html.erb (3.2ms)
Rendered items/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
```

This is the controller:

```
def index
 @items = Item.search(params[:search])
end
```

and this is the model:

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stocks
  attr_accessible :nombre, :espesor, :material, :quantity
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks
   attr_accessible :stocks_attributes
   self.per_page = 50
   #  def self.search(search)
   #     Item.where("nombre LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")

   #  end

    def self.search(search_term)
    where("nombre LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
    end

    protected
    end
```

and the search form in the view:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, :method => 'get', :id => "items_search" do %>
 <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
 </p>

<div id="items"><%= render 'items' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I have a _items.html.erb file which has the items to render, that part works because no matter my input on the search bar, it always shows all the items

This is the ouput when i try to use .search method in the console

```
 2.3.0 :041 > Item.search("blanca")
 NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x0000000203fc58>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-     4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
      from (irb):41
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried `.search` in rails console? the log doesn't seem like it actually performed the `where`

Comment: Please add the partial for completeness as well.

Comment: the partial is working, otherwise i wouldnt get the full list of items, the problem is on the query not passing

Comment: I added the output when i try to use search in the console

Comment: @frenciaj, I have added my answer. Let me know if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you defined the class method `search` in `item.rb`? Cause the error says that there's no `search` method defined on the `Item` class. However, try if the following works for you.

You only want to search if the form is being submitted. You can use the `present?` method to know if the search term was actually passed.

Modify your controller to

```
def index
  @items = params[:search].present? ? Item.search(params[:search]) : Item.all
end
```

Note that an object is `present` only if its not blank. This is handy because if someone enters " " in the form, you shouldn't search for an empty space in the `nombre` field but display all the records in the `items` table.

If the form was not submitted, `Item.all` will be executed.

Modify your class method to

```
def self.search(search_term)
  where("nombre LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
end
```

You don't need a `Item.where` because the class `Item` is the current context on which the `where` method is called. Note that I have changed the pattern to `%#{search_term}%` cause you don't always want to match strings ending with some pattern.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I modify this based on your answer, but its still not getting the query, the log shows the same as i had previously

Comment: @frenciaj, Thats really strange. Were you able to do `Item.search(term)` in the rails console? What do you have you in your `index` action? Looks like you are accessing a user's items and limiting them to 50 records. Please post your latest code in the `index` action.

Comment: Items controller 
def index
  @items = params[:search].present? ? Item.search(params[:search]) : Item.all
  end

the user part is because devise is installed for authentication

Comment: @frenciaj, if you have a look at the logs, you can see that `limit` and `sort` are done on the records. Were you able to do `Item.search(term)`? in the console?

Comment: no, i cant i get the following error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `search' for #<Class:0x0000000203fc58>

Comment: There's a problem with your model then. Can you update the question with your code in `item.rb`?

Comment: I updated the question, now is showing the full item.rb model

Comment: believe it or not, its not working on localhost either, so the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I fixed it!! apparantly the name items of the var was used somewhere else and it was being overwritten, i changed the name to filtered_items and its working...

Comment: now i need you to tell me how to disable the site to displaying the params on every page...

Comment: In `application.hml.erb`, there should be a statement `<%=  params.inspect %>`. Remove it and you should be good to go.